# Gridview PageIndex not changing on page_Load event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change pageindex on page_Load event but its not working.
I can change page by clicking links in the page after page loaded.
If this info necessary GridView in UpdatePanel.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     /*...Some Codes...*/
     //I'm trying to change page like this.
     GridView1.PageIndex = Index;
     GridViewPageEventArgs ea = new GridViewPageEventArgs(GridView1.PageIndex);
     GridView1_PageIndexChanging(sender, ea);
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender,GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
}
```

Comment: Yes After i binded gridview im trying to change page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you need to rebind the data to your gridview after you change the page index.